# Hash string to generate a long sequence

Tags: algorithm, hash, cryptography

I'd like to have a long sequence of characters or numbers, determined by a hash string passed to some widely-used function. For example, I have a string `a94a8fe5ccb19ba61c4c0873d391e987982fbbd3` and if I pass it to a set of functions from some widely used opensource library, it would return me 100k symbols in the same order every time I execute it on any machine?

I suppose it's something to do with seed numbers like in Minecraft, but I'm not sure where to start, so please advise.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Easiest is to use a stream cipher such as ChaCha. A stream cipher is a CSPRNG that produces as much output as you want given a key (e.g. the bytes represented by the hex string you've shown). For non-secure you can use an LSFR. If you know the output size in advance then in theory you can also use a XOF such as SHAKE128 or SHAKE256.

If you want to have "symbols" then you can use a *specific* rejection sampling mechanism such as "simple discard". If you have N symbols then you take the number of bits required to represent N (usually to a byte boundary, discarding the unnecessary bits). Convert this into the number `i`; if the number is too high then you repeat the process. Now `i` is the index into the *alphabet*, i.e. a sequence of all known symbols.